# What authentication mechanism is required by python and azure service bus

Tags: python-2.7, amqp, azureservicebus, sasl, gssapi

i'm wanting to use python, under linux, to connect with the azure service bus.  to that end, i'm using qpid-proton and amqp protocol.

however, when i try connecting to the service bus, i get the following error:

> qpid.messaging.exceptions.AuthenticationFailure: sasl negotiation
>   failed: no mechanism agreed

I understand that the service bus supports the SASL username/password scheme, but what else is required?  I have some vague notion that GSSAPI is used.

Comment: I have a vague notion that PLAIN is used.